# How do you say "tipping point" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking of "[kulmino](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kulmin.html#kulmin.0o)", "alveno de nehaltigebla ŝanĝo", "deklivpunkto"... It's about not being able to go back from that point on, so there's probably a great way to express it in Esperanto, I just can't find the right expression. It could also be "point of no return", but I think a good translation of tipping point would show that it's different from point of no return. There might be a short amount of time between the tipping point and the actual point of no return."nerenversebla punkto" is one way of translation point of no return, but I'd like something focusing on the tipping, the movement... Also something that focuses on the kulmino, the top. "postkulmina" "kulminpreterpaso"
Another idea, from Guillaume, is renverspunkto
simile al : deirpunkto, alvenpunkto
= punkto kie okazas deiro, alveno, renverso

Comment: I think what you describe is a "point of no return", which isn't exactly the same concept as a "tipping point". Which one shall your question be about?

Comment: It's a good question, and I'm not sure. It depends on the translation :-D

Answer (score 4):

*kriza/krita punkto*.

krita: rilata al punkto, stato aŭ kvanto, kie ia esenca ŝanĝiĝo okazas (PIV). *Kriza* kaj *krita* aperas kiel samsignifaj vortoj en PIV.

Answer (score 3):

Eble ***punkto de nereiro*** aŭ ***nereira punkto***

Ekz. el Tekstaro:

> la atmosfera koncentriĝo de forcejaj gasoj atingis punkton de nereiro,
>   kreante la kondiĉojn por malvarmiĝo

Answer (score 0):

Mi nun proponas "krizajn sojlpunktojn". Tiel la parto de la krizo estas klara, la punkto estas tie, kaj la kompreno/metaforo de la sojlo atingita.